# Facebook Unity SDK 6.0 re request for declined permission

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Facebook has modified their implementation for permission. Now user can select between different permissions and can decline some permissions. I used to try and get all the permissions at the start so that app doesn't ask again for the permissions. Now user can decline the permission. Now, I want to change my implementation. For example, user has not given me the permission for friends list then ask user again. Issue is I cannot find a way to re ask user to provide the permission for Unity SDK. I went through their docs as well.

if I call

FB.Login("user_friends", LoginCallback);

and user declines the permission then if I call above function again. It says you have already authorized this app.

On Facebook, there is a whole article regarding permissions but there is not information for unity sdk.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#permissions

Anyone else having this issue ? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beta SDK 6.1 fixed this issue

> Canvas login will now re-ask for declined permissions

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/change-log

Answer (score 0):

What i did was to loop through the permissions query from Facebook API.
Then you can check if it's granted or not per permission base.

If it isn't granted, do a fb.logout and an fb.login with the same permissions as before.
This should clear your token and re-request the permission.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In the end, I ended up using Facebook iOS SDK function i.e. requestNewPublishPermissions. It worked fine.